# in React, why setState() Priority execution than setTimeout？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in React, `setState()` is async function, and `setTimeout()` is also async function(somebody think, in some condition, `setState()` may be sync function?),
why `setState()` priority excution than `setTimeout()`?

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1}, ()=>{
        console.log("In callback " + this.state.val);
    });
    console.log("Direct call " + this.state.val);   
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("begin of setTimeout" + this.state.val);
        this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1}, ()=>{
            console.log("setTimeout setState callback " + this.state.val);
        });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("setTimeout of settimeout " + this.state.val);
        }, 0);
        console.log("end of setTimeout " + this.state.val);
    }, 0);
}

> Direct call 0
> In callback 1
> begin of setTimeout 1
> setTimeout setState callback 2
> end of setTimeout 2
> setTimeout of settimeout 2
```

Comment: To sum it up, asynchronous code is not guaranteed to execute in any specific order. Consider looking into Promises to solve your issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: Or if you need to do something after changing state, do `this.setState( {}, () => mycallback() );`

Comment: Kindly mark it as answer if the same code works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use setTimeout.
setState function does support callback function.

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```